# ¿Cómo reviso qué cambios se hicieron en un servidor Linux, y qué usuario los realizó?

Tags: linux

Buen día.

Hace un par de meses, la fecha y hora de un servidor en el que trabajaba se regresó al 1 de enero del 2000 a las 00:00:00 horas. Eso provocó varios fallos en datos que se guardaron bajo esos parámetros de tiempo. Además, el archivo php.ini del servidor también sufrió cambios, evidentes cuando noté que el valor *timezone* estaba en "Europe/Berlin", y no en el correctamente definido mucho tiempo atrás. El resto de la máquina funciona con normalidad.

Lo que específicamente necesito saber es lo siguiente: qué archivo o qué lugar debo revisar dentro del sistema para hallar el momento en que ese cambió sucedió, y quién lo provocó.

Tengo acceso a la carpeta en donde se guardan los logs del sistema. A saber, en /var/log, desde la raíz. Pero no sé qué debo revisar dentro de esos archivos para hallar el registro. Hay varios archivos y directorios ahí. Los directorios son estos:
[image: imagen1]

... Y los archivos son estos:
[image: imagen2]

Se supone que los registros están en algún lugar de esos, verdad?

Gracias por su ayuda ;)

Comment: Si asumimos que el cambio de hora se hizo invocando un llamado a`sudo` un buen lugar para revisar podría ser `/var/log/secure`

Comment: Quizás el log `messages` y sus rotaciones (`messages-201711*`) puedan darte información útil.

Comment: Si no hay ningun acceso no autorizado, se puede suponer tambien que se ha producido algun fallo hardware (fallo de la pila del reloj interno) o de sincronización incorrecta con algun servidor de hora !! Si entras en modo "paranoico" como admin del sistema, deberás presuponer que tienes el servidor comprometido y deber realizarle una auditoria de seguridad por si está "crackeado" y tienes algun exploit, rootkit, etc... Pero este tema ya es muy denso y creo que se aparta de toda la ayuda que podamos darte aqui...

Answer (score 0):

Esa **auditoria** te va a llevar algo de trabajo... ademas de averiguar como pudo acceder a ciertos ficheros....

Varias cosas:auditoria

Para ver exactamente el cambio de cada fichero o directorio puedes usar el comando stat

```
   $ stat prueba.tar 
      Fichero: prueba.tar
      Tamaño: 10240         Bloques: 24         Bloque E/S: 4096   fichero regular
    Dispositivo: 801h/2049d Nodo-i: 7341513     Enlaces: 1
    Acceso: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (54353/usuario)   Gid: (65362/grupo)
          Acceso: 2017-11-30 12:35:02.993410858 +0100
    Modificación: 2017-11-30 12:35:03.009410937 +0100
          Cambio: 2017-11-30 12:35:03.009410937 +0100
        Creación:
```

Para ver login del usuario y a que hora puedes usar el comando **last**

Comment: Es preferente agregar solo una respuesta y agregar actualizaciones en la misma.